# how to load a polymer based website in a webview in an android app

Tags: web, polymer

I have made a project based on polymer. It works fine on any web browser. I want to make an android app with only a webview that loads my polymer website. The webview is working fine for all websites but not for my polymer based website. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any other version of Android other than Lollipop you will surely run into this problem, that's because html `import`s are relatively new to HTML so it is implemented only in the very latested builds of chromium.

One way to get around the problem is to install an app by Google called [Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview), which brings the latest features including html `import` of Chromium to older devices.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Bidelman has [just posted an article](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/webview.html) on how to do this on the official Polymer site.

If you need support for older versions of Android you should look into [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) by Intel. It's covered a bit in the article as well.